# SPARQL how to return date value that has no prefix?

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to query some data from https://data.niod.nl/PoolParty/wiki/WO2_Thesaurus using SPARQL queries.

One thing I am unable to accomplish is to return the value of `startDate` (or `endDate` in some cases). A `startDate` may look like `<startDate xmlns="http://schema.org/" rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">1942-05-03</startDate>`, see the RDF fragment below:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://data.niod.nl/WO2_Thesaurus/events/6556">
    <dcterms:created rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-07-17T11:56:18Z</dcterms:created>
    <dcterms:creator rdf:resource="https://cultureelerfgoed.poolparty.biz/user/jongmal"/>
    <dcterms:source xml:lang="nl">Erik Schumacher, 1942. Oorlog op alle fronten. Leven in bezet Nederland (Houten: Spectrum, 2017)</dcterms:source>
    <startDate xmlns="http://schema.org/" rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">1942-05-03</startDate>
    <skos:broader rdf:resource="https://data.niod.nl/WO2_Thesaurus/2030"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Compared to the other elements, which have prefixes such as `rdf`, `dcterms`, or `skos`, `startDate` does not have a prefix.

My current query (without `startDate`) looks like this:

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?s ?prefLabel ?scopeNote WHERE {
  ?s skos:inScheme <https://data.niod.nl/WO2_Thesaurus/events/4329> .
  ?s skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel .
  ?s skos:scopeNote ?scopeNote .
  FILTER (lang(?prefLabel)= "nl") .
}
LIMIT 50
```

So, my question is, **how do I add the value of `startDate` to the result of my query?**

Comment: your line `<startDate xmlns="http://schema.org/" ` indeed indicates how the URI is made given that `xmlns` is there. There URI of the property is `http://schema.org/startDate`

Comment: the query is `PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT ?s ?prefLabel ?scopeNote ?startDate ?endDate WHERE {
  ?s skos:inScheme <https://data.niod.nl/WO2_Thesaurus/events/4329> .
  ?s skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel .
  ?s skos:scopeNote ?scopeNote .  ?s schema:startDate ?startDate . OPTIONAL {?s schema:startDate ?endDate }
  FILTER (lang(?prefLabel)= "nl") .
}
LIMIT 50`

Comment: for the future, you also could have simply added another triple pattern `?s ?p ?o .` and then select `?p` and `?o` to see the data available.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much for your reply! Thanks also for the additional suggestion!